# How to get the number of event "actual participants" from the API?

Tags: civievent, api

I have an event with a price set which allows multiple registrations on one email.  It accurately counts the number of people registered against the maximum allowed.  How do I get the number of "actual participants" from the API?  This snippet only counts the number of registration records:

{crmAPI var="ParticipantS" entity="Participant" method="getCount" sequential="1" event_id=$event.id } 
Count = {$ParticipantS.count}

Answer (score 2):

You can total up the participants by looking up the line items.

https://gist.github.com/ginkgomzd/5ca327a0711fdb586529a4936accb244

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should check each individual Participant record for the actual number of participants and count them manually. With manually I mean you can count them with smarty code.

Answer (score 0):

I would also check out and install the excellent Summary Fields extension from Jamie McClelland (see https://civicrm.org/extensions/summary-fields ) which among many other summaries shows counts for Events attended per contact and also see Events -> Dashboard -> Event Summary (which might be in core, or might be enabled after installing the Summary Fields extension - not sure which ).